# How to align flex items like a table?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flex boxes displaying information and I would like their row contents to line up like a table.

They each take 50% of their parent and resize accordingly.

The problem is I can't get the "Content" to line up vertically because my titles are variable sizes.

Here is the correct layout working as a table:
[image]
Here is what I have with flex:
[image]

I have tried setting a min-width on my titles but then when I resize my browser, the flexbox with shorter content shrinks more than the other.

Looking specifically for a flexbox solution as there are some responsive adjustments which break for a table.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8k6qyrovjl

**Update**: After help from @seantunwin it looks like the issue is a piece of content being a very long string eg. a url (updated code). It seems to push everything out of sync

Comment: Can you upload an image to show us how the tiles should be?

Answer (score 2):

Set `.row`'s first child to `50%` of it's flex parent's width, or whichever value suits you.

To account for text wrapping you may also set the `.row`'s second child to `50%` or some other value which is acceptable to you.

There is also a note in the below code as an idea for further aesthetics.

```css
.row :first-child {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.row :nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  /* Align to bottom of cell if you're inclined for long text in adjacent */
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Example: [a fork from the example in OP](https://codesandbox.io/s/p58zxlmovj)

Comment: This also results in misaligned items because text might wrap causing a flex item title to be smaller than the width specified: https://imgur.com/a/uDFwsyM

Comment: @dingdingding, I added some CSS to the second child and provided an example.

Comment: Thank you @seantunwin this is very nearly perfect. The issue it would seem now is that a very long single string messes it up